# Node.js require installed module from changed path

Tags: node.js

I installed a node module using npm install and it was placed in home/username/node_modules directory. I changed part of the source code of this installed module and then for committing on subversion I had performed a symlink as mentioned here:

[Follow symlinks in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24850844/follow-symlinks-in-svn)

Now I plan to restructure my project files including the installed node module. Is it possible to do away with the symlink and simply require the module by specifying the path?